# Map is not showing in google_maps_place_picker

Tags: flutter, google-place-picker

I'm trying to use google_maps_place_picker
but the map is not shown just a white screen, and these are the first two lines of errors.

> MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method
> checkServiceStatus on channel
> com.baseflow.flutter/location_permissions) E/flutter ( 6811):
> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception:
> PlatformException(error, java.lang.IllegalStateException: Trying to
> create a platform view of unregistered type:
> plugins.flutter.io/google_maps E/flutter ( 6811): at
> io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformViewsController$1.createPlatformView(PlatformViewsController.java:97).

Thanks for any solutions

Comment: Please format the code in your question

Answer (score 0):

From [flutter documentaion](https://pub.flutter-io.cn/packages/location_permissions)

Add to your code :

```
import 'package:location_permissions/location_permissions.dart';
ServiceStatus serviceStatus = await LocationPermissions().checkServiceStatus();
```

Basically you need to get permission, and that's why you get

> MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method
> checkServiceStatus on channel
> com.baseflow.flutter/location_permissions)